# Phpunit in docker on M1 painfully slow

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose

I've just been given a new MacBook Air to replace my linux machine as I much prefer MacOS. However I am having massive issues with running PHPUnit within my container.

The container in general is running slowly with our site taking what seems like forever to load, I have docker preferences set to 4CPU and 4GB of ram, I am happy to increase this, but when testing it didn't make a difference.

An example, if I ran `vendor/bin/phpunit tests` locally I would get something like:

```
PHPUnit 9.5.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

..                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 00:01.835, Memory: 56.50 MB
```

However, running those same tests using `docker-compose exec app vendor/bin/phpunit tests` I would get the following for the SAME tests:

```
PHPUnit 9.5.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

..                                                                  2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 00:17.646, Memory: 58.50 MB
```

I've come across things like Mutagen but can't tell if I'm already using it as it might be packaged with docker, and I've also tried a couple tweaks to my volume like so:

```
volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/site:cached
```

OR

```
volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/site:delegated
```

Any other suggestions from fellow suffering M1 users.

Comment: Bit anecdotal, but I've seen an M1 user run the same code (luaJIT) in MacOS and Rosetta, and Rosetta was 4x faster. Might be worth trying.

Comment: Got any information how I can *choose* to run this using rosetta? I have it installed but not sure how that would work

Comment: Unfortunately no :( although I went back and checked, apparently he was running the code inside of an x64 linux VM on his M1 (Rosetta is just the compatibility layer)

Comment: Yeah thought so, damn

Comment: So sad, I'm having tha same problem... I tried with multipass, corima to virtualize a linux and nothing works...

Comment: I'm with same problem. And just for information, the slow happen is also outside docker container. I did run with PHP directly and is slower too. And looks that is just PHpUnit slower, the other things like Laravel callers, is ok to me.